# how generate a constant Unique id from python

Tags: python, constants, uuid

my application need use python generate a  constant Unique id for run machine.

the constant Unique id mean is :
**anytime in the same machine ,generate  Unique id is always the SAME Unique id.**

(maybe like system uuid,but my application not run root,cant't get system-uuid).

btw,i think python uuid model not good for me:
uuid1():use time,gen a uuid,this is not a  constant Unique id
uuid3():cant use some string gen a uuid,but this uuid same in any machine.

Thanks!

the same machine: The same cpu+motherboard+OS instalation+same disk.
action :
uuid1():use time gen a uuid,this is not a  constant Unique id

Comment: define "the same machine". The same cpu? cpu+motherboard? The same OS instalation? The same disk? All of these?

Comment: Suppose admin creates a couple of identical virtual machines; do you expect your program to know which one it's running in?

Comment: Try the mac address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address

Answer (score 1):

You could try [snowflake](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/snowflake/). If you have root, the ID can be persistent for the whole machine; otherwise, it can just save the ID in a file you have permission to create.

Disclosure: I wrote it. :)

Comment: Is it cross platform?