# How get my system Mac adders in python

Tags: python, mac-address

I tried get Mac adders in python 3.6.2,i wrote code bellow to get it:

```
from uuid import getnode 
address=getnode()
h = iter(hex(address)[2:].zfill(12))
print(":".join(i + next(h) for i in h))
```

but it print mistake,for example,if my Mac adders is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:12,it print 
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:25.
How fix it?

Comment: `uuid.getnode()` is not a good way to get the MAC **address**. It could return the address of any device in the system or even be random.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address

Comment: Recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159150/4909087) from the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the `netifaces` module.

1. Import the module:

   ```
   >>> import netifaces
   ```
2. Get all the interfaces present

   ```
   >>> netifaces.interfaces()  
   ['lo', 'eth0', 'tun2']
   ```
3. Extract Mac address of selected interface eg. eth0

   ```
   >>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_LINK] 
   [{'addr': '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'}]
   ```