# How to get Windows MacID using python script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, nic

```
import sys
import os
mac = 0
def mac_list():
    global mac
    if sys.platform == 'win32': 
        for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"): 
            if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'): 
                mac = line.split(':')[1].strip().replace(':','-') 
                break 
    else: 
        for line in os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig"): 
            if line.find('Ether') > -1: 
                mac = line.split()[4] 
                break 
    return mac
```

- I got this code from StackOverflow only. This works really good as my requirement to get MAC ID of Windows machine.

-**My Problem is When machine is connected to both Wlan and Ethernet this code fetching both activated MACids. I want to get only one active MAC(preferaly ethernet 1st and then if it's not available then wlan) can anyone recommend proper condition to filter the appropriate mac.**

Answer (score 1):

If by MAC id you mean MAC address, then you could use `netifaces` : [Getting MAC Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address)

I recommend you read https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces

Comment: Thank you, @Anes please comment solution regarding to the code mentioned above.