# How do I parse the output of getmac command?

Tags: python, windows, mac-address

After doing some research I found out that the best way to get the Ethernet MAC address under windows is the "getmac" command. (getmac module of python does not produce the same!!). Now I want to use this command from within a python code to get the MAC address. I figured out that my code should start something like this:

```
import os
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    os.system("getmac")
    do something here to get the first mac address that appears in the results
```

here is an example output

```
Physical Address    Transport Name                                            
=================== ==========================================================  
1C-69-7A-3A-E3-40   Media disconnected                                        
54-8D-5A-CE-21-1A   \Device\Tcpip_{82B01094-C274-418F-AB0A-BC4F3660D6B4}
```

I finally want to get 1C-69-7A-3A-E3-40 preferably without the dashes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First of all, I recommend you find ways of getting the mac address more elegantly. [This question's answer seems to use the uuid module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address), which is perhaps a good cross-platform solution.

*Having said that*, if you want to proceed with parsing the output of a system call, I recommend the use of Python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). For example:

```py
import subprocess

output_of_command = subprocess.check_output("getmac")
```

This will run `getmac` and the output of that command will go into a variable. From there, you can parse the string.

Here's how you might extract the mac address from that string:

```py
# I'm setting this directly to provide a clear example of the parsing, separate
# from the first part of this answer.

my_string = """Physical Address Transport Name
=================== ==========================================================
1C-69-7A-3A-E3-40 Media disconnected
54-8D-5A-CE-21-1A \Device\Tcpip_{82B01094-C274-418F-AB0A-BC4F3660D6B4}"""

my_mac_address = my_string.rsplit('=', 1)[-1].split(None, 1)[0]
```

The first split is a *right split*. It's breaking up the string by the '=' character, once, starting from the end of the string. Then, I'm splitting the output of that by whitespace, limiting to one split, and taking the first string value.

Again, however, I would discourage this approach to getting a mac address. Parsing the human-readable output of command line scripts is seldom advisable because the output can unexpectedly be different than what your script is expecting. You can assuredly get the mac address in a more robust way.

Comment: I still don't understand how you get that output into my_string!? I have tried almost every thing, getmac module of python, uuid.getnode, etc. None of them provide the right answer. They all produce the mac address of WLAN or Bluetooth device. I need the the mac address of the Ethernet adapter. Only getmac command under windows produces the right output.

Comment: my_string would be the output of `subprocess.check_output("getmac")`

Comment: I also thought that and tried, but didn't work. my_mac_address becomes the same as my_string, but all in one line!

Comment: First I had to convert the byte to string and then use your formula. Thanks.