# getting a MAC address with Python

Tags: python, mac-address, arp

I found a way to get a MAC Address with python using Kamene.
Link included: [Structure ARP in Python](https://www.codestudyblog.com/cnb11/1124193721.html)

There is a module called **Tools**, that I can't find.  I tried `pip install tools` but it's the wrong tools.
Any ideas?

This also could be added to some other answers for how to return a MAC Address with Python on other posts.

Comment: This is not a module, usually this is a file/folder where the user stores some python tools that they wrote, if they are not available then you have to write them on your own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting MAC Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address)

Comment: yes it does answer my question can the thread please be closed?